# Create some if from list of string / Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

First sorry for my english...

I need your help to fix a difficult. I have a python script to check some parameters, with this parameters I check some conditions but I would like to add the possibility for the user to create an another check from a string...
To give you an exemple, I will save some coditions in string than I will split to have the check name, limit value,delay,condition (<,>,=...). And from this list (string splited) I woud like to create an "If 'value' 'condition' 'limit value' " but I don't find how to write this IF from my list.

```
parameter="O2_alert,O2,0.015,<"

para1=parameter.split(',')   # ==> para1 =["O2_alert","O2","0.015","<"]
alert_name=para1[0]
value_name=para1[1]   # it's a name of a variable in my script not a value
limit_value=para1[2]
condition=para1[3]

#  And I woul like to have

if value_name condition limit_value :
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you give some example input and output
Examples speak better than English

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to transform the string ``"O2_alert,O2,0.015,<"`` into the statement ``if O2 < 0.015:``, correct? Is it feasible for you to store your data into a dict instead of variables, so that you would run ``if data["O2"] < 0.015:``? Are your users trusted, or do you need to protect against malicious content?

Comment: Yes I thought to use a dict but how to do for ">" ? I will add some filter to check if the expression is ok or not. I remeber to seen a solution to check if a string contain special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
parameter="02_alert,2,0.015,<"

para1=parameter.split(',')   # ==> para1 =["02_alert","02","0.015","<"]
alert_name=para1[0]
value_name=para1[1]   # it's a name of a variable in my script no a value
limit_value=para1[2]
condition=para1[3]


if eval(f"{value_name} {condition} {limit_value}"):
    print('abcd')
```

It works for you.

Comment: Oh thank you !!! You have find a perfect solution also I try to find it since few days.... I learn alone but Python is a beautiful langage it's a perfect tool.

Comment: Note: ``eval`` allows execution of arbitrary code. Do not use if users should not be allowed to run malicious content.

Comment: Yes, I read actually eval() documentation and it's specified but thanks for this instruction. 
I will add some filter